# What is the best Separator to Separate Multiple Emails?

Tags: php, email, bcc

I am using `mailto` link to populate `bcc` of users default email program.

```
$mem_email=" ";    
$sql="SELECT email_address FROM employee";
$contacts = $db->query($sql);
while($contact = $db->fetchByAssoc($contacts))
{
    if($contact['email_address']!="" && $contact['email_address']!=NULL)
    {
        $mem_email.=$contact['email_address'].", ";
    }
}

header("Location: mailto:?bcc={$mem_email}");
```

What is the best separator to separate multiple emails in bcc field: `,` or  `;` ?

In my case, I am using `,`.

Comment: If you are using plain old `mailto` anchor then yes, that is the best way.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The separator should be a comma (`,`) and there should not be a space.

See [RFC 6068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068).

Comment: thank's , RFC 6068 link is really great to learn 'mailto' URI Scheme .

Comment: @UriNetanel https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068

Answer (score 16):

Here's a late caveat in case anybody needs it:

Even though RFC explicitly recommends a comma, Microsoft Outlook will use the "list separator character" defined in the regional settings. Your mailto links may not work correctly for your Windows + Outlook users whose systems are configured with a different list separator such as semicolons. Outlook will simply refuse to split the e-mail addresses with commas.

Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Well, I seem to have a counterexample to this. I have Windows 10 and Outlook 365, and my regional settings clearly specify comma as List Separator. In fact it doesn't allow me to change it to anything else, at least not under my setting of U.S. English. But Outlook absolutely requires a semicolon separating recipients. In fact when I type a recipient, it automatically inserts a semicolon and space after every one (even the last one on the line). I can edit out the space and it still works, but if I go to the Outbox and look at the mail, the space has been reinserted by Outlook.

Comment: OK, a modification to the above comment. Upon further investigation, I have discovered an option in Outlook. (In my version,) you can click File - Options - Mail, scroll down to the Send Messages section, and check "Commas can be used to separate multiple message recipients". If this is checked, Outlook actually takes the commas, and after about 3 seconds (as it validates the given Email addresses against its own address book) actually changes them to semicolons. So now people can argue over who should work harder to adapt:  the developer creating the mail program, or the Outlook user.

Comment: @phantomflash, good to know that they somewhat improved the behavior in under ten years.

Comment: Since my comments, I have read one source saying this feature was introduced in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 3):

#### TLDR Solution

TLDR Answer: Use a `,` without spaces to separate e-mail addresses.

[RFC6068: The 'mailto' URI Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) (published October, 2010) is only a ***proposed standard***, and [it is not an accepted, Internet standard.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Standard#:%7E:text=The%20IETF%20also%20defines%20a,prior%20to%20an%20Internet%20Standard.)  It also doesn't discuss comma-separation.

#### TLDR Caveats/Gotchya's

- Be aware (per [RFC6854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6854#section-3)) that you shouldn't comma-separate addresses in an e-mail's `Sender` field (for security reasons).
- Many services allow spaces with the `,`, so an ideal regex for splitting would be `/\s*,\s*/`.
- Outlook and Exchange (and other X.400/X.500-compliant software) supports using a `;`.  This is because the X.400/X.500 specification that treats semicolons as a valid name-separator (see [RFC1485](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1485), published July, 1993).  Going forward, using `,` is recommended.

#### The Source

To quote the original proposed standard, [RFC2822: Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), published April, 2001...

> #### 3.6.3. Destination address fields
>
> The destination fields of a message consist of three possible fields,
> each of the same form: The field name, which is either "To", "Cc", or
> "Bcc", followed by a comma-separated list of one or more addresses
> (either mailbox or group syntax).
>
> ```
> to              =   "To:" address-list CRLF
>
> cc              =   "Cc:" address-list CRLF
>
> bcc             =   "Bcc:" [address-list / CFWS] CRLF
> ```

This proposed standard was accepted as a draft standard in October, 2008, with [RFC5322: Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).  I would quote the text there, but they decided to keep it exactly as it is.  An update was proposed in March, 2013, with [RFC6854: Update to Internet Message Format to Allow Group Syntax...](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6854): you shouldn't be allowing comma-separated values in the `Sender` field, because then it's uncertain who really triggered sending the e-mail.  To quote this RFC, RFC6854...

> #### 2.1.  Replacement of RFC 5322, Section 3.6.2. Originator Fields
>
> ...The from field and the sender
> field SHOULD NOT use group syntax; rather, the from field SHOULD use
> only the mailbox-list syntax and the sender field SHOULD use only
> mailbox syntax (see RFC 6854, Section 3).  If the sender field uses
> group syntax, the group MUST NOT contain more than one mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code,

```
implode(',', $contacts);
```

above code will give comma separated emails.

Comment: I have used `$mem_email.=$contact['email_address'].", ";` and it is doing well ,

Comment: I used `$mem_email.=$contact['email_address'].",";` and it's doing well . Is `implode(',', $contacts);` has any additional benefit ??

Comment: mansoor, with your version, your concatenated email address string will have a trailing comma, but using implode will just put a comma between the addresses, not at the end. Aside from that, it's purely aesthetic - simpler code looks nicer and is easier to follow, but ultimately it's up to you -- the tiny differences in optimisation won't make any difference in this instance.

Comment: following on from my last comment, implode won't check for empty or null values in the array, so you would need to array_filter() before imploding, if you were to do it that way.